The error occurred due to a mismatch in JVM target versions: compileDebugJavaWithJavac is set to 1.8, while compileDebugKotlin is set to 17
I have this error on flutter when running flutter run :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).

  Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
  Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation 


The problem is that I think it's not coming from my code but from the package 'google_api_headers'.
I absolutely try everything, i have all my dependencies and android, gradle version up to date.
Bellow the result of ./gradlew -v
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:    2024-07-11 14:37:41 UTC
Revision:      d536ef36a19186ccc596d8817123e5445f30fef8

Kotlin:        1.9.23
Groovy:        3.0.21
Ant:           Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
Launcher JVM:  22.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 22.0.1+8-16)
Daemon JVM:    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home (no JDK specified, using current Java home)
OS:            Mac OS X 14.6.1 aarch64

My JDK version is 17
enter image description here
Bellow settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.8" apply false
}

include ":app"

Bellow build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // [required] flutter_background_geolocation
        maven { url "${project(':flutter_background_geolocation').projectDir}/libs" }
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        // [required] background_fetch
        maven { url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs" }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 34                // or higher / as desired
    targetSdkVersion    = 34                // or higher / as desired
    minSdkVersion       = 23                // Required minimum
    appCompatVersion    = "1.4.2"           // or higher / as desired
    playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"  // or higher / as desired
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Below app/build.gradle
plugins {
   id "com.android.application"
   id "kotlin-android"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
   id "com.google.gms.google-services"  // Google Services plugin
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.mycompany.test"
    compileSdkVersion 34

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs (for flutter_local_notification)
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}

My pubspec is up to date too flutter pub upgrade --major-versions.
